# No Semaphore in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, semaphore

I'm developing with Silverlight 4.

Threads are there. WaitHandles (AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent) are there too. But no Semaphore? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created my own [Semaphore for Silverlight](http://modosansreves-coding.blogspot.com/2011/08/semaphore-in-silverlight.html).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's no semaphore in Silverlight. The Threading library for SL is restricted. But you can make your own very easily. Here's an example:

```
public class Semaphore
{
    private object Mutex { get; set; }
    private int Count { get; set; }
    private int Max { get; set; }

    public Semaphore(int max = 1)
    {
        Mutex = new object();
        Max = max;
    }

    public void WaitOne()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (Mutex)
            {
                if (Count < Max)
                {
                    Count++;
                    return;
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        lock (Mutex)
        {
            if (Count >= 0)
            {
                Count--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is based on the second answer of [this post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/20199.aspx), which is preferred over the first for actually being thread safe.

Comment: Please note that the "green" answer on that link is not thread-safe. Go with the version that shows locking.